# Update array element by id with mongo query

Tags: mongodb

Is there a query to update sc from 15 to let's say 17 for array element with id 2 for _id 1? I've this structure in mongodb:

```
  { _id: 1,
    lb: [
       {
          id: 2,
          sc: 15
       },
       {
          id: 3,
          sc: 16
       }
        ]
  }
  { _id: 2,
    lb: [
       {
          id: 5,
          sc: 34
       },
       {
          id: 6,
          sc: 12
       }
        ]
  }
```

I have one more: is there a way to write a query to update as you just said and if there is no array element with updated id, insert a new one. I don't want to make two queries - first to check if element exist and update it, second to append it if there is no such. It would be nice to append it in one query. Thanks. –  user3045201 1 hour ago

Comment: Isn't it the element with id 1 in your example? sc is 15 for the first element of your array.

Comment: Yes and I want it to be 17

Comment: You should generalise your question's example

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can update it using the following query :

```
db.myCollection.update({"_id" : 1, "lb.id" : 2},{$set : {"lb.$.sc" : 17}})
```

AFAIK, It is not possible to do what you want in a single query. You have to make seperate queries for each of them.

Comment: You are welcome. I have updated my answer for your second question. Also if it worked, you can mark it as an answer.

Comment: I tried this and got "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$set' in '$set' is not valid for storage." -- am using golang+mongo