# Mongoose Update Nested Array Object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection as follows

```
 [
  {
    actions: [
      {
        _id : ObjectId('641b34b7aa7f4269de24f050')
        participants: [
          {
            _id : ObjectId('641b33c3aa7f4269de24ef10')
            referenceId: "641b3414aa7f4269de24efa5",
            name: "Person one",
            email: "example@gmail.com"
          },
          {
            _id : ObjectId('61bb9105362e810ae9a6826f')
            referenceId: "641b3414aa7f4269de24ef4g",
            name: "Person two",
            email: "example2@gmail.com"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to update participants' name by filtering participants' referenceId.

As an example, I want to update the document where referenceId  = 641b3414aa7f4269de24efa5 and then update the name to "Person 1".Then the document will look like this after update

```
[
  {
    actions: [
      {
        _id : ObjectId('641b34b7aa7f4269de24f050')
        participants: [
          {
            _id : ObjectId('641b33c3aa7f4269de24ef10')
            referenceId: "641b3414aa7f4269de24efa5",
            name: "Person 1",
            email: "example@gmail.com"
          },
          {
            _id : ObjectId('61bb9105362e810ae9a6826f')
            referenceId: "641b3414aa7f4269de24ef4g",
            name: "Person two",
            email: "example2@gmail.com"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there any way that I can perform this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update array element by id with mongo query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262405/update-array-element-by-id-with-mongo-query)

Comment: @ray Nope. I was confused with the update object inside the nested array. Your example has only one array.Not a nested one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

almost similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324876/arrayfilters-in-mongodb)
you can use [`arrayFilters`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/3.6/#arrayfilters) option to **specify which elements to modify in an array field**

filtered positional operator [`$[<identifier>]`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) is used to identify the array elements that match the `arrayFilters` conditions for the update operation. In this example the first action and in that the first participant ( `referenceId` `641b3414aa7f4269de24efa5`)

```js
db.collection.update(
  { "actions.participants.referenceId": "641b3414aa7f4269de24efa5" },
  { $set: { "actions.$[action].participants.$[participant].name": "Person 1" } },
  { arrayFilters: [{ "action.participants.referenceId": "641b3414aa7f4269de24efa5" }, { "participant.referenceId": "641b3414aa7f4269de24efa5" }] }
)
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A6rI3qcvTT0)

**EDIT**
in this example even this works

```js
db.collection.update(
  {},
  { $set: { "actions.$[action].participants.$[participant].name": "Person 1" } },
  { arrayFilters: [{ "action.participants.referenceId": "641b3414aa7f4269de24efa5" }, { "participant.referenceId": "641b3414aa7f4269de24efa5" }] }
)
```